# Is travel pass cheaper than taxi for 4 adults in Europe

Tags: public-transport, europe, switzerland, rome

I'm traveling to various cities in Europe like Lucerne, Rome, Vienna- which have tourist passes/ travel passes with unlimited access to all transportation, and sometimes sightseeing discounts and entries.

I'm not able to figure out if it's cheaper for 4 adults to just buy their own tickets, and travel by taxi, than to buy these passes.

I'm also totally confused about the many passes Rome offers. I'm going in peak season- so definitely want skip the line tickets to main attractions like colosseum, vatican etc- which pass would be best for me and my group, or are individual tickets ideal?

Also are there many senior discounts in Europe for non-EU citizens?

Comment: The situation will most likely be very different from city to city and most importantly based on what trips you will make during your stay (and the duration of the stay). Also note that in some places getting 4 people in a single taxi may not always be possible.

Comment: @jcaron Can you advise me for any particular city? Our longest stays are in Rome and Lucerne.

Comment: It’s probably best if you ask one question per city, including in each case details such as the duration of your stay, whether you will travel to/from the airport, what other trips you will make, possibly the area where you are staying, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you stay at any accommodations within Lucerne, you will get a completely free [Lucerne Card](https://www.luzern.com/en/footernavigation/services/visitor-card-lucerne/) that lets you use all transport within city boundaries.  Lucerne is also compact enough to be quite walkable, and Swiss taxis are *very* expensive, so using public transport here is the obvious choice.

Generally speaking, I find "tourist passes" bundling entrance fees/discounts and transport to be poor value, you're often better off buying them separately.  But this will depend on the city, your specific interests, how many places you plan to visit every day, etc etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I found your response extremely helpful- particularly about the Lucerne Card- which I had no idea existed. I'm also generally vary of passes, so I'll just do an itemised list with a comparison

Comment: @VPrah Glad to help, please accept the answer (click the check mark) if it worked for you!

Answer (score 4):

In most European cities the main mode for exploring the town is your own pair of feet. Often the historic centre is pedestrianised. If you need to cover longer distances there is public transit, and that is, even for four persons, going to be cheaper than taking a taxi.

For example: A 24 hour ticket for all public transit in Rome is only 7,- euro. A single ticket valid 75 minutes is only 1,50. And public transit is fully integrated, so you can use buses, trams, metros and urban trains at will.

Taxi will be more expensive.